# Grails 2.3.2 doesn't invoke ForkedTomcatCustomizer

Tags: grails, groovy, ajp

I upgraded my grails application to grails 2.3.2 from 2.2.4. I had previously used _Events.groovy eventConfigureTomcat() closure to establish an ajp connection from apache httpd mod_jk.  When upgrading, I found that this is no longer supported, but the recommended approach is to implement org.grails.plugins.tomcat.ForkedTomcatCustomizer customize() method where I could establish ajp connector.  [See grails docs and search on ForkedTomcatConnector](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.2/guide/commandLine.html).

My problem is that the code is never invoked.

I implemented the ForkedTomcatCustomizer in the /src/groovy directory. Here is the code:

```
package org.grails.plugins.tomcat

import grails.util.Environment
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat

/**
 * Forked tomcat customizer adds ajp connect to support apache ajp in dev env
 * from within IDE
 */
class ForkedTomcatCustomizer
{
    void customize(Tomcat tomcat)
    {
        println("In the ForkedTomcatCustomizer.customize() method")
        if (Environment.getCurrent() == Environment.DEVELOPMENT)
        {
            def ajpConnector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol")
            ajpConnector.port = 8009
            ajpConnector.protocol = "AJP/1.3"
            ajpConnector.redirectPort = 8443
            ajpConnector.enableLookups = false
            ajpConnector.setProperty("redirectPort", "8443")
            ajpConnector.setProperty("protocol", "AJP/1.3")
            ajpConnector.setProperty("enableLookups", "false")
            tomcat.service.addConnector ajpConnector
            println "Added ajp connector"
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone seen / resolved this?

Comment: Have you enabled forked execution with `grails.project.fork.run=true`?

Comment: I had tried "grails.project.fork.run=true" on my full app when I first migrated it, but forgot to add this property to my test app.  I just added the property to my test app and reran and it has no affect.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug.

Refer to the code snippet below from `TomcatDevelopmentRunner`... the `forkedClassLoader` member is still null when `invokeCustomizer` is called (from the superclass constructor).. As you can see the NPE is swallowed and the process fails silently...

```
    private void invokeCustomizer(Tomcat tomcat) {
        Class cls = null
        try {
            cls = forkedClassLoader.loadClass("org.grails.plugins.tomcat.ForkedTomcatCustomizer")
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // ignore
        }
        ...
```